# Django: Syntax error in urls.py

Tags: django, django-urls

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^events/', include('events.urls')),
)
```

and here is my events.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from events import views


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^tonight/$', views.tonight, name='ev_tonight'),
)
```

I am getting the following error after running the server:

```
Exception Type:     SyntaxError
Exception Value:
```

invalid syntax (urls.py, line 8)

Am I missing something here?

Edit: Attaching the traceball

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin

Django Version: 1.4
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'events')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  89.                     response = middleware_method(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/common.py" in process_request
  67.             if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in is_valid_path
  531.         resolve(path, urlconf)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  420.     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  298.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  328.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  323.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/home/bhavish/startthedark/startthedark/urls.py" in <module>
  8.     (r'^events/', include('events.urls')),
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py" in include
  24.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)

Exception Type: SyntaxError at /admin
Exception Value: invalid syntax (urls.py, line 8
```

)

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code. Check for some special symbols in the code file... Or check events.urls for an error ...

Comment: Guess you can remove the quotes surrounding events.urls

Comment: @Pramod, no you can't unless you specifically import the events module.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error being raised is in events/urls.py -- check that file carefully. There may be some extra white space at the end of it that you can't see. (The syntax error is supposedly on line 8, but I don't see 8 lines in what you pasted)

You can also try importing that file directly from a python shell, to see if it parses at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of "importing that file directly from a  python shell". It worked! An exta '~' while copying the content of urls.py

Comment: Thanks for the pro-tip to try and use the python shell. Found it instantly!

Answer (score 0):

maybe this line:
`(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),`
should be changed to (parenthesis added):
`(r'^admin/', include('admin.site.urls')),`

Comment: That would cause a `NameError` at runtime, not a `SyntaxError` at import.